# Como faço para atualizar meus dados na tabela usando o EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

```
 var contactado = ContactadoRepositorio.ObterListaContactadoPorCodigo(procedimentoVM.CodContactadoPessoa); //obtenho o contactado pelo id obtido;

 foreach (var c in contactado)
 {
     var contactadoPessoa = new ContactadoPessoa()
     {
         Codigo = c.Codigo,
         CodigoPessoa = c.CodigoPessoa,
         Nome = c.Nome,
         CodigoProcedimento = procedimento.Codigo
     };

     ContactadoRepositorio.Atualizar(contactadoPessoa);
 }

//Com o objeto obtido eu atualizo as propriedades que eu quero salvar no BD

public void Atualizar(ContactadoPessoa contactadoPessoa)
{
    this.Context.ContactadoPessoas.Attach(contactadoPessoa);
    this.Context.Entry(contactadoPessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
    this.Context.SaveChanges();

}

//Metodo para Atualizar e salvar no BD
```

Ao correr o código recebo o seguinte erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Forte.Rastreador.Model.ContactadoPessoa'
>   failed because  another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value.   This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to  'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values.   This may be
>   because some entities are new and have not yet received
>   database-generated key values.   In this case use the 'Add' method or
>   the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then  set the state of
>   non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate

Comment: O que está acontecendo? poderia melhorar um pouco sua pergunta? Da algum erro?

Comment: qual é o erro retornado?

Comment: Attaching an entity of type 'Forte.Rastreador.Model.ContactadoPessoa' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: justamente esse erro!

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta para incluir o erro. Edite sua pergunta e inclua o código do método `ObterListaContactadoPorCodigo` e a classe `ContactadoPessoa`. O que pretende actualizar é `CodigoProcedimento`?

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa `Attach` para este caso. Modifique para:

```
public void Atualizar(ContactadoPessoa contactadoPessoa)
{
    // this.Context.ContactadoPessoas.Attach(contactadoPessoa);
    this.Context.Entry(contactadoPessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
    this.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O mais simples é fazer assim:

db é o context instanciado assim: `nomeContext db = new nomeContext();`

Depois faça isto:

```
var registro = db.NomeDaTabela.FirstOrDefault(c => c.chavePrimaria);

registro.nome_do_campo1 = 'novo conteudo1';
registro.nome_do_campo2 = 'novo conteudo2';
.
.
.

db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

O erro mais comum é querermos criar um objeto (registro) como este do zero sem usar o próprio objeto que foi localizado com o FirstOrDefault(). Se atribuirmos o id e tudo mais neste registro sem ele ser localizado, o objeto que criamos é falho e dá pau.

Comment: Esqueci de dizer que, sem localizarmos o registro correto que queremos fazer update, com o FirstOrDefault(), não conseguiremos atualizá-lo usando só o ID dele contido na Tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Você usa attach apenas para adiconar uma entidade ao contexto que ainda não esta sendo monitorada por ele.

Como sua entidade já esta no contexto e você esta modificando suas propriedades, você pode salvar as mudançãs no contexto diretamente

```
this.Context.Entry(contactadoPessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Ou simplesmente usar o EntityState implicitamente:

```
this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que a coluna CODIGO seja a chave primária da tabela ContactadoPessoas.Tente fazer assim

```
var contactado = ContactadoRepositorio.ObterListaContactadoPorCodigo(procedimentoVM.CodContactadoPessoa); //obtenho o contactado pelo id obtido;

 foreach (var c in contactado)
            {
                var contactadoPessoa = this.Context.ContactadoPessoas.FirstOrDefault(cp => cp.Codigo == c.Codigo);

                    contactadoPessoa.CodigoPessoa = c.CodigoPessoa,
                    contactadoPessoa.Nome = c.Nome,
                    contactadoPessoa.CodigoProcedimento = procedimento.Codigo

                ContactadoRepositorio.Atualizar(contactadoPessoa);
            }
//Com o objeto obtido eu atualizo as propriedades que eu quero salvar no BD

  public void Atualizar(ContactadoPessoa contactadoPessoa)
    {
        this.Context.ContactadoPessoas.Attach(contactadoPessoa);
        this.Context.Entry(contactadoPessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.Context.SaveChanges();

    }
```